# Regular expression for email, why doesn't it work?

Tags: regex, email

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the best regular expression for validating email addresses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-for-validating-email-addresses)

I've been trying to do some regex for email filtering.

Allowed

```
anystring@example.com
any.string@example.com
a@example.com
```

Not allowed

```
any.st.ring@example.com
.a@example.com
a.@example.com
@example.com
```

This one accepts all allowed... but also `a.@example.com`

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9]+[\.]?){1,2}@([a-zA-Z0-9]+\.)+(com)$
```

This one accepts all allowed... except `a@example.com`!

Added `[^\.]` before `@`

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9]+[\.]?){1,2}[^\.]@([a-zA-Z0-9]+\.)+(com)$
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Why the heck isn't `any.st.ring@example.com` allowed?

Comment: @NullUserExceptionఠ_ఠ stupid school assignment...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`^[a-zA-Z0-9]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+)?@([a-zA-Z0-9]+\.)+com$` will accept your 'allowed' emails and reject the others.

Naturally, that will not match all generally valid emails.  See http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html for a discussion on email regular expressions.